# How to remove a tag, and preserved the text in the element using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to remove the element tag and want to preserve the text inside the tag. I use the replace function of RegExp but it removed everything: The tag and the text inside the tag.

I dont want that, I want to remove the tag only. Clean up the text, remove the tags, I want to present the text only.

```
var str = str.replace(/<.>[^.]*\/.>/, "");
```

I used this, but there's a problem, it also removed the text inside it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about

`var obj = $('#element');`

`var str = obj.text();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're indeed using jQuery, and want to remove all tags, then simply set the .html() to the .text()

```
var e = $("#yourelement");
e.html(
    e.text()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
var str = "<foo>bar</foo>"; alert(str.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ""))
```

Consider using real parsing and DOM manipulation instead.  Correct processing of HTML using RegExp is very difficult.